# Unable to extend schema within a verified sub domain directory

Tags: subdomain, microsoft-graph-api

I live in an enterprise environment where most of our production domains are currently non-routable (e.g. `.local`).

I tried extending the schema but since the non-routable cannot be verified and the default `.onmicrosoft` I don't think could either. My enterprise allows me to easily create subdomains so I attached it and verified for testing purposes and ran into the same verified domain error.

[Per the documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/schemaextension_post_schemaextensions#request-2), I should be able to either us the ID of my domain name or just the scheme name and get 8 random-alpha-chars added. Neither approach works in this case.

```http
POST: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/schemaExtensions

{
    "id": "idmdomain.sub.domain.net_Owners",
    "description": "Owners of the group",
    "targetTypes": [
        "Group"
    ],
    "properties": [{
            "name": "PrimaryOwners",
            "type": "String"
        },
        {
            "name": "SecondaryOwners",
            "type": "String"
        }
    ]
}
```

**Message Received:**

```
{
    "code": "BadRequest",
    "message": "Your organization must own the namespace idmdomain.sub.domain.net as a part of one of the verified domains.",
    "request-id": "1c7363f9-d54b-408a-8b29-2c0d2a94280a",
    "date": "2018-03-22T21:47:22"
}
```

Comment: Also if there was a way to do this as a multivalued attribute instead that would be much better for me.  I see that I should be able to create multivalued, but when I tried I received an error message saying it wasnt supported. https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/multivaluelegacyextendedproperty_post_multivalueextendedproperties

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/extensibility_overview#schema-extensions):

> If you already have a vanity `.com`,`.net`, `.gov`, `.edu` or a `.org` domain that you have verified with your tenant, you can use the domain name along with the schema name to define a unique name, in this format `{domainName}_{schemaName}`.
>
> For example, if your vanity domain is `contoso.com`, you can define an id of, `contoso_mySchema`. This is the preferred option.

So in your example, `idmdomain.sub.domain.net_Owners` should simply be `domain_Owners`. It shouldn't include `idmdomain`, `sub`, `net` or any  `.`.

Comment: Hey Marc, 

Per that same documentation you provided, I should also be able to leave my domain off and I cannot. I receive an access denied message when I remove my subdomain as the root is not verified in my directory.

>If you don’t have a verified vanity domain, you can just set the id to a schema name (without a domain name prefix)

Comment: What do you get when you pass it `owners`?

Comment: Insufficient privileges to complete the operation. I'm executing from a global admin account.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Marc for pointing me in the correct direction. Even though my app had the correct delegated permissions (Directory.AccessAsUser.All) I now understand that I needed to execute this change in the user context instead of application as application is not supported.

For those that come behind me {domainName}_{schemaName} works if you validate your domain, if dont and you just leave schemename then the generated guid works as documented.  I recommended reviewing the two links below as they were what finally unlocked the puzzle for me.

**Helped me understand how this is working (authentication vs authorization)**
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/rest

**Helped me setup postman to quickly validate**
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/softwaresimian/2017/10/05/using-postman-to-call-the-graph-api-using-azure-active-directory-aad/

I should add for the postman route, a few changes...

**Auth URL**
https://login.microsoftonline.com/yourtennantid/oauth2/authorize?resource=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com

**Access Token URL**
https://login.microsoftonline.com/yourtennantid/oauth2/token

**Scope** = Directory.AccessAsUser.All